# How to get the cumulative returns with DAX in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: return data]

Any one can help on how to write expression in DAX to 
calculate the cumulative returns grouped on id and cat
such at

cumulative return = cumprod(1+return) for all days

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
Cumulative Return = CALCULATE(
    PRODUCTX(Returns, 1 + Returns[Return]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(Returns[Date]),
        Returns[Date] <= MAX(Returns[Date])
    )
)
```

Comment: will you explain the filter section? Is it filtering from the current date to the beginning date?  product x is multiplying the percent change to the beginning date.

Comment: @GoldenLion your understanding is correct. ALLSELECTED cancels the original filter context (which is a single date), and the second clause applies a new filter containing the cumulative period.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, where I showing the accumulated value of 60k:

```
AccumulativeReturn = CALCULATE(
    PRODUCTX(EOG, 1 + EOG[PercentChange]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED(EOG[Date]),
        EOG[Date] <= MAX(EOG[Date])
    )
)*60000
```